# How to find the longest and shortest linked list?

Tags: algorithm, list, data-structures

Consider the following shape, it's the representation of a collection of items, not of a shape at all.

I have a list of N elements, in this case 10.

Each element has the following properties:

- ID (the number in red color)
- A pair of attributes that indicate '**from**' and '**to**', values are `String` or `Integer` (in parenthesis). They're not pointers to other objects.
- A pointer to the previous element (default value is `null`)
- A pointer to the next element (default value is `null`)

*Ignore the blue line for now.

[image]

This is how I assign the pointers to the `previous` and the `next` object of each element:

```
item1 =   { 'id': 1, 'from': 'a', 'to': 'b', 'prev': None, 'next': None}
item2 =   { 'id': 2, 'from': 'b', 'to': 'c', 'prev': None, 'next': None}
item3 =   { 'id': 3, 'from': 'c', 'to': 'd', 'prev': None, 'next': None}
item4 =   { 'id': 4, 'from': 'd', 'to': 'e', 'prev': None, 'next': None}
item5 =   { 'id': 5, 'from': 'e', 'to': 'f', 'prev': None, 'next': None}
item6 =   { 'id': 6, 'from': 'f', 'to': 'a', 'prev': None, 'next': None}
item7 =   { 'id': 7, 'from': 'f', 'to': 'g', 'prev': None, 'next': None}
item8 =   { 'id': 8, 'from': 'g', 'to': 'h', 'prev': None, 'next': None}
item9 =   { 'id': 9, 'from': 'h', 'to': 'i', 'prev': None, 'next': None}
item10 = { 'id': 10, 'from': 'i', 'to': 'a', 'prev': None, 'next': None}

items = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10]

for p1 in items:
    for p2 in items:
        if p1['to'] == p2['from']:
            p1['next'] = p2['id']
            p2['prev'] = p1['id']
```

Executing the previous code, my collection of items become (I think of this as a double linked list):

```
items = [
    {'id': 1,  'from': 'a', 'to': 'b','prev': 10,'next': 2},
    {'id': 2,  'from': 'b', 'to': 'c','prev': 1,'next': 3},
    {'id': 3,  'from': 'c', 'to': 'd','prev': 2,'next': 4},
    {'id': 4,  'from': 'd', 'to': 'e','prev': 3,'next': 5},
    {'id': 5,  'from': 'e', 'to': 'f','prev': 4,'next': 7},
    {'id': 6,  'from': 'f', 'to': 'a','prev': 5,'next': 1},
    {'id': 7,  'from': 'f', 'to': 'g','prev': 5,'next': 8},
    {'id': 8,  'from': 'g', 'to': 'h','prev': 7,'next': 9},
    {'id': 9,  'from': 'h', 'to': 'i','prev': 8,'next': 10},
    {'id': 10, 'from': 'i', 'to': 'a','prev': 9,'next': 1}
]
```

How can I find the (shortest) list that goes from 1, to 6 and then back to 1? That is, the blue line in the above shape, this:

```
1 (a,b)
2 (b,c)
3 (c,d)
4 (d,e)
5 (e,f)
6 (f,a)
```

How can I find the (longest) list that goes from 1 to 5, then to 7 to 10, then back to 1? That is, this:

```
1 (a,b)
2 (b,c)
3 (c,d)
4 (d,e)
5 (e,f)
7 (f,g)
8 (g,h)
9 (h,i)
10 (i,a)
```

Does the linked list help me to achieve this more easily?

Is there any other data structure that could help me to resolve this more efficiently?

Comment: This is a bad graph structure, you'd better distinguish nodes and links. You have 10 nodes and 11 forward links and 11 backward links, each node should have at least a list of outward links. Your problem is the shortest path problem, very well known (search on the web). Dijkstra algorithm is the most known of all.

Comment: What about the longest problem @Jean-BaptisteYunès?

Comment: Well shortest PP is easy to solve, its complexity is n^2, if n is the number of nodes. While longuest PP is known to be NP-hard, meaning that you basically need to test every possible path. Search on the web.